# Use system.web.UI.Control.FindControl to retrieve multiple controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I've got a webpage with a repeater.
currently i have a single repeater which shows all my articles

```
<asp:repeater runat="server" ID="rptArticles" DataSource="<%# CurrentArticles %>">
do something
```

Inside all these articles are a few checkboxes which you can use to check the articles and do some actions with them.

To retrieve and return the checkboxes I have the following methods

```
    Protected ReadOnly Property ArticleRepeater As Repeater
        Get
            Return DirectCast(FindControl("rptArticles"), Repeater)
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overridable Function GetSelectedArticles() As String
        Dim Checkboxes As HtmlInputCheckBox() = DataConvert.FindControlsByType(Of HtmlInputCheckBox)(ArticleRepeater, True)
        Dim SelectedValues As String() = (From cbx In Checkboxes Where cbx.Checked Select cbx.Value).ToArray
        Return String.Join(";", SelectedValues)
    End Function
```

these methods do their work perfectly at the moment.

but now I want to filter my articles a little bit more so I have a repeater inside the initial repeater, which filters them and only shows them with their specific filter.
so my code looks like this now.

```
<asp:repeater runat="server" ID="rptArticles" DataSource="<%# CurrentArticles %>">
    <asp:repeater runat="server" ID="childRepeater" DataSource="<%# Filter(Container.DataItem) %>">
    do something
```

But now my GetSelectedArticles function doesn't work anymore.
The rptArticles repeater doesn't have control of the checkboxes anymore, hence i can't retreive them.

Does anybody know how i can replace the Property "ArticleRepeater" in such a way I can use it again or it returns the child repeaters?

note: I already tried swapping the names around, but because i have multiple childrepeaters the findcontrol function doesn't work anymore.

Answers can be given in either VB.Net or C# I can convert these languages pretty easy

Edit: I forgot to mention. it still has to work for legacy code which uses the old single repeater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion of how you could possibly work this around. Please note that I have never seen this `FindControlsByType` method before, so I am going to assume you are using something similar to this one (taken from [here](http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/control/findcontrolsbytype)):

```
public static List<T> FindControlsByType<T>(this Control ctrl)
{
  return ctrl.GetChildren().OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

This version is missing a second parameter, boolean, purpose of which is yet unclear to me.

The idea is to retrieve all child repeaters, and then for each of them retrieve checkboxes inside. Combined this should give you all checkboxes inside the `rptArticles`:

```
var childRepeaters = DataConvert.FindControlsByType<Repeater>(ArticleRepeater);
var checkboxes = childRepeaters.SelectMany(r => DataConvert.FindControlsByType<HtmlInputCheckBox>(r)).ToList();
```

Note that this code is using LINQ's `SelectMany`. `checkboxes` now should contain all checkboxes found inside the outer repeater

Comment: Thank you for your response. This fixed my problem.
the boolean is for internal purposes.

The code inside findcontrolsbytype was slightly different from the code you posted. After adjusting it worked correctly.